# Sum of two columns from pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query

```
SET @sql = N'
SELECT distinct ' + @columns2 + ', p1.*

   FROM  
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT 
  [CALF_AN]
      ,[CALF_NPERIODE]
      ,[CNT_ID]
      --,[PER_ID]
    ,[MontantAccoss]
  from [Reporting].[dbo].[TEMPAccoss]
  WHERE  [CALF_AN]=2014
) AS j
PIVOT
(
 sum([MontantAccoss])
  for [CALF_NPERIODE] in ('+@columns1+')
) AS p  ON p.CNT_ID = COT1.CNT_ID 
 INNER JOIN 
(SELECT 
  [CALF_AN]
      ,[CALF_NPERIODE]
      ,[CNT_ID]
      --,[PER_ID]
    ,[MontantHorsAccoss]
  from [Reporting].[dbo].[TEMPHorsAccoss]
  WHERE  [CALF_AN]=2014
) AS j
PIVOT
(
 sum([MontantHorsAccoss])
  for [CALF_NPERIODE] in ('+@columns1+')
) AS p1  ON p1.CNT_ID = COT1.CNT_ID;';
PRINT @sql;
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

I am looking to perform a sum sum([MontantAccoss])+sum([MontantHorsAccoss]) of every column from pivot p and pivot p2 ? Any idea ? Many thanks in advance .

Comment: Pls share table schema & sample data.

Comment: Do you want to perform this SUM sum([MontantAccoss])+sum([MontantHorsAccoss]) inside pivot's aggregate function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
SET @sql = N'
SELECT distinct ' + @columns2 + ', p1.*, SUM(p.s, p1.s1)

   FROM  
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT 
  [CALF_AN]
      ,[CALF_NPERIODE]
      ,[CNT_ID]
      --,[PER_ID]
    ,[MontantAccoss]
    ,SUM(MontantAccoss) [s]
  from [Reporting].[dbo].[TEMPAccoss]
  WHERE  [CALF_AN]=2014
) AS j
PIVOT
(
 sum([MontantAccoss])
  for [CALF_NPERIODE] in ('+@columns1+')
) AS p  ON p.CNT_ID = COT1.CNT_ID 
 INNER JOIN 
(SELECT 
  [CALF_AN]
      ,[CALF_NPERIODE]
      ,[CNT_ID]
      --,[PER_ID]
    ,[MontantHorsAccoss]
    , SUM(MontantHorsAccoss) [s1]
  from [Reporting].[dbo].[TEMPHorsAccoss]
  WHERE  [CALF_AN]=2014
) AS j
PIVOT
(
 sum([MontantHorsAccoss])
  for [CALF_NPERIODE] in ('+@columns1+')
) AS p1  ON p1.CNT_ID = COT1.CNT_ID;';
PRINT @sql;
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```